# Nodes of a UK street by name of road AND town/city/county

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

Is it possible to get nodes of a particular street of a particular town/city/county/country? [This](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/AXj) is not enough.

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
way["name"="Kennington Road"]; //all roads named such on the planet
//how do I limit it further?
// I know I can do add this
// way["name"="Kennington Road"](around:500,51.49595,-0.11124);
// that is OK but not ideal.

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rushed asking the question, if duplicate, please mark it so and happy to delete/remove it.

This is what I was looking for:

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
area[name="London"]->.a;

way(area.a)["name"="Kennington Road"]; // only roads contained in "london"

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```